# Early load of Magnific-Popup works in HTML files but not PHP files. Is this possible in PHP files?

Tags: php, magnific-popup

My website/blog uses HTML files, but for the actual blog pages the files are PHP due to the commenting script I use. It uses the [Magnific-Popup lightbox](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) throughout.

Anyway, if I place the popup loader down at the bottom of each (HTML) file, that means that when a user sees an image at the top of the screen, and clicks on it a bit too early, it may just proceed directly to the http://www.website.com/image.jpg page rather than fire the popup, due to the popup loader not having been loaded yet. To fix that possibility I moved the loader to the HEAD of the HTML files, and that fixes the issue. If the image isn't fully loaded and the user clicks on the popup, it pops up and continues loading in popup mode. However, I did that with my PHP files, but they act as if the popup loader was still down at the bottom of the page, and the popup won't come into effect until the whole page has fully loaded. Is there any way around this, or is this some kind of limitation to PHP?

I don't imagine it would make any difference, but here's the relevant coding I include in the HEAD of my HTML and PHP files.

For HTML files:

```
<script src="/scripts/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<!--#include virtual="/grabbag/popup.html" -->
```

For PHP files:

```
<script src="/scripts/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<?php include("../../../../grabbag/popup.html"); ?>
```

I have other scripts running, but they all appear after jquery and the Magnific Popup stuff. The Magnific Popup CSS file comes before jquery and the Magnific Popup javascript files.

The popup.html file, which used to appear at the bottom of the pages, includes the following:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.image-popup-vertical-fit').magnificPopup({
            type: 'image',
            delegate: 'a',
            closeOnContentClick: true,
            mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
            image: {
                verticalFit: true
            }
        });
        $('.parent-container').magnificPopup({
            delegate: 'a', // child items selector, by clicking on it popup will open
            type: 'image'
            // other options
        });
        $('.image-popup-vertical-fit').magnificPopup({
            type: 'image',
            closeOnContentClick: true,
            mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
            image: {
                verticalFit: true
            }

        });

        $('.image-popup-fit-width').magnificPopup({
            type: 'image',
            closeOnContentClick: true,
            image: {
                verticalFit: false
            }
        });

        $('.image-popup-no-margins').magnificPopup({
            type: 'image',
            closeOnContentClick: true,
            closeBtnInside: false,
            fixedContentPos: true,
            mainClass: 'mfp-no-margins mfp-with-zoom', // class to remove default margin from left and right side
            image: {
                verticalFit: true
            },
            zoom: {
                enabled: true,
                duration: 300 // don't foget to change the duration also in CSS
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your browser doesn't care how the HTML file was generated. Look at the document source in your browser to find what's wrong.

Comment: @Jocelyn Thanks for the clarifying for me that the HTML and PHP come through the browser the same. I don't think there's anything wrong with the PHP file(s), but perhaps all the scripts for the social media buttons on the PHP blog pages are slowing things down, even though they appear way down at the bottom of the page(s). I'll play around with it all.